# How to initialize a DirectX 12 Debug Layer Interface

Tags: com, directx, directx-12

I've been looking at the DirectX12 Documentation.
It uses what are called Com pointers (`ComPtr`). in the guide most of the `ComPtr`s have a guides showing how a certain ID3D12 Interface is initialized.
for example `ID3D12CommandList` is initialized using `ID3D12Device::CreateCommandList(...)` & the `ID3D12Device`.
Although I'm trying to initialize the `Debug` layers that come in `d3d12sdkLayers.h` headers.
I can't find anywhere in the documentation that shows how to initialize any of these layers (aside from the main DebugInterface itself.

Here is the list of interfaces I'm referring to [/direct3d-12-sdklayers-interfaces](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/direct3d12/direct3d-12-sdklayers-interfaces)

for example how do I initialize the [`ID3D12DebugCommandList`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/d3d12/nf-d3d12-id3d12device-createcommandlist)

Comment: Enable the debug layer (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/d3d12sdklayers/nf-d3d12sdklayers-id3d12debug-enabledebuglayer) and QueryInterface for `ID3D12DebugDevice` on an instance of `ID3D12Device`, same for `ID3D12DebugCommandList` on an instance of `ID3D12CommandList`, etc.

Comment: Hey thanks. I realized I didn't understand what COM model was fully; I didn't understand that some interface implementations are only reachable/provided from instances of of a particular kind. but also I don't know why the docs don't show this though. where would I have found out that `ID3D12DebugCommandList` needs to be queried from a regular `ID3D12CommandList`.. is this just a naming standard that is known.

Comment: Not this is not some kind of standard, this is specific to these interfaces. Usually, what you can get from an interface is documented, but I don't actually remember how I know these ones.

Answer (score 1):

The Debug Layer must be initialized before you create the device. This is done as:

```
#if defined(_DEBUG)
    // Enable the debug layer.
    {
        ComPtr<ID3D12Debug> debugController;
        if (SUCCEEDED(D3D12GetDebugInterface(IID_PPV_ARGS(&debugController))))
        {
            debugController->EnableDebugLayer();
        }
    }
#endif
```

Note that you have to have the "Graphics Tools" Windows optional feature enabled for this to actually succeed. See [this blog post](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/visual-studio-2015-and-graphics-tools-for-windows-10/).

If the debug device is available at runtime, you can use COM **QueryInterface** to get specific interfaces from the DirectX 12 objects. For example:

```
ComPtr<ID3D12DebugCommandList> dbgCommandList;
if (SUCCEEDED(commandList->QueryInterface(IID_PPV_ARGS(&dbgCommandList))))
{
    D3D12_DEBUG_FEATURE t = dbgCommandList->GetFeatureMask();
...
}
```

See [Programming DirectX with COM](https://learn.microsoft.com/windows/win32/prog-dx-with-com) and [Anatomy of Direct3D 12 Create Device](https://walbourn.github.io/anatomy-of-direct3d-12-create-device/).

> `ComPtr` is just a C++ smart-pointer wrapper for COM interfaces that ensure the reference counts are properly updated. See [this wiki page](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTK/wiki/ComPtr) for more information.

Comment: Actually, the specific fact `ID3D12DebugXXX` can be queried from `ID3D12XXX` (when debug layer is enabled) doesn't seem to be documented anywhere, the doc should be updated IMHO.